# ASP.NET UserControl Variable Lifeproblem

Tags: asp.net, properties

- Got a `Site.Master` (Masterpage)
- Got `Default.aspx` (Page)
- And in the `Default.aspx`, there is a UserControl `LoginUserControl.ascx` placed

Now my problem:

In the **LoginUserControl** I check if Login is right.
If yes, then I set the Property `IsLoggedIn` on the `Default.aspx` to **true**:

```
    //Inside LoginUserControl.ascx
    if (/*Login is Ok*/)
    {
         ((Default)Page).IsLoggedIn = true;
    }
```

So, now I need this Information in my Masterpage `Site.Master`
I must know if User is logged in or not.. I do this:

```
    //Inside Site.Master
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((Default)Page).IsLoggedIn)
        {
             //Do Something
        } 
    }
```

But its **ALWAYS** false! Why? I thought I set the **IsLoggedIn = true** ?! Why is it then false? Is it a Lifecycle problem and what I must do, that it works :(

Comment: You left off when in the lifecycle IsLoggedIn is getting set to true. If you debug and step through, Does the master page Page_Load happen before IsLoggedIn is set to true? That's your problem then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the property IsLogged on to the viewstate of the page.

```
public bool IsLoggedOn { 
    get { return ViewState["IsLoggedOn"]==null?false:Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["IsLoggedOn"]); }
    set { ViewState["IsLoggedOn"] = value; }
}
```

Or if the property is used over multiple pages you should add it to the Session (replace ViewState with Session)

Comment: I don't think this will help. The problem is the master page is accessing the property before it is set by the user control.

Comment: ViewState did it, thx! I will mark the question as Answer in 7min

Comment: @eMi - if you navigate away from the page and then navigate back does it still work?

Comment: @eMi - I really think your issue relates to the order in which master/page/user control events are being handled.

Answer (score 0):

This is more that likely a page lifecycle issue. Page_Load in the Site.Master runs before Page_Load in your user control. What you will need to do is find the appropriate page and control events in which to apply your code.
[This page](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2006/06/30/Complete+Lifecycle+Of+An+ASPNet+Page+And+Controls.aspx) has a complete breakdown of page/control/user control event life cycles and should help (scroll down to the merged events).
I think your best options are to either set IsLoggedIn property during the user controls Page_Init event or retrieve and act on it during the master page's Page_PreRender event.