# ASP.NET Set a Global constant variable?

Tags: asp.net

Working on the Loginmechanism... But got problems..

I have a UserControl (`LoginUserControl.ascx`) placed on a `Default.aspx`, which is in my Masterpage(`Site.Master`)...
Over the UserControl, the User can login... 
Now I would like to set a **global Variable**, which won't change its Value, wherever I navigate...

A Variable like, **IsLogged, (true/false)**.
Because I got problems with Viewstate and when I change an other Site (by Example to `MyOtherSite.aspx`), IsLogged is then **false**...

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its depending on each user session. Write the Value in the Session.

```
Session["IsLogged"] = true;
```

Comment: Sorry, one more question ;) Are you doing the "old" asp or asp.net development ?

Comment: @eMi You'll need to post some code in order for someone to help you place the line that dknaack suggested.

Comment: You can set this variable after the user login.

Comment: maybe this is enough.. There I didnt fix the problem, when I move over other sites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820222/asp-net-usercontrol-variable-lifeproblem